# How to prevent unnecessary imports with py2exe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, py2exe

I have a console script that includes the following import statements:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import sys
```

I'm trying to create a Windows executable for this script using `py2exe`, but having some trouble, as it seems to be bringing in all sorts of things that it does not need (overzealous module searching, perhaps?).

I am using the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import numpy
import sys
import zmq
import os

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + \
                     os.path.pathsep + os.path.split(zmq.__file__)[0]

setup(
    console=['script.py'],
    data_files=[(".",["config_file.txt",])]
)
```

I had to include the recursion line and the stuff for `zmq` due to errors that arose during initial compiling. The compilation works with this example, but results in a `dist/` folder over 300MB...

After compilation, I can see that it brought in libraries such as `matplotlib`, `PIL`, `PySide`, `PyQt`, all of `scipy`, `statsmodel`, `tcl`, `wx`, `tornado`, and others.

Is there anyway to prevent these from being imported? I assume that they are somehow optional dependencies of `pandas` or `numpy`, but they are not used in the script at all, since it is just a console application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually exclude the packages you don't need as suggested in py2exe's [OptimizingSize](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/OptimizingSize) page. I've duplicated their example in case the page ever goes away.

```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   import sys; sys.argv.append('py2exe')

   py2exe_options = dict(
                 ascii=True,  # Exclude encodings
                 excludes=['_ssl',  # Exclude _ssl
                           'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'locale', 
                           'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar'],  # Exclude standard library
                 dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll'],  # Exclude msvcr71
                 compressed=True,  # Compress library.zip
                 )

   setup(name='<Name>',
         version='1.0',
         description='<Description>',
         author='Ofer Schwarz',

         console=['script.py'],
         options={'py2exe': py2exe_options},
         )
```

Comment: Thank you! I browsed around what I thought was all of those pages, but I guess I missed that one.